# Redis query by expiration time

Tags: redis, ttl

Let's say I have two Redis keys

```
1) Test1 -> expiry/ttl after 2 days
2) Test2 -> expiry/ttl after 1 day
3) Test3 -> expiry after 1month
```

Is it possible to just query keys by TTL or expiry time?

I could have read the keys & compare the ttl but that would be very expensive operation.

Comment: There is no redis command to query by ttl. The only solution would be to scan the entire keyspace. A really very expensive operation as you have already mentioned.

Comment: Thanks , I will have to look for another efficient way